# How to capture the name of the Build selected in Test Manager for Coded UI Test VS2012

Tags: c#, testing, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

I need to pass the name of the Build that was assigned by `Microsoft Test Manager` for the `CodedUI Test`.

For example, before the execution of a test I select the Build and start execution. In my `CodedUI Test` I need to capture the name of the Build and put in a variable. I need this because every time I run my test I need to invoke the `.exe` of the application under test that was generated by my Build.

So if I know the name of the Build I can identify which is the path of the `.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the value from `TestContext.Properties["__Tfs_BuildNumber__"].ToString()`.

The Properties dictionary has a lot of other useful information in it as well. It's worth having a peek in there to see if there's anything else that's useful (such as the `BuildDirectory` for example)